# DMVPN Phase 2 question

Tags: cisco, routing, vpn

One of the issues with phase 2 is doing summarization at the hub for the other spoke networks. Currently, the spokes are summarizing their own networks via EIGRP to the hub and the hub is then re-advertising this summary route to the remaining spokes. In phase 3, I will do all of the summarizing at the hub, but I'm not seeing that as a huge benefit compared to the spokes doing it.

Are there any issues with doing the summarization at the spokes in phase 2? What are the benefit of having the hub do summarization in phase 3 compared to the spokes doing summarization in phase 2? To me, it looks like its accomplishing the same goal. I feel like there is something that I'm not realizing here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Robot

IMHO Only while your DMVPN is part of your bigger network I can see point of doing summarization at hub. Unskilled summarization at hub could create many issues and pretty much destroy DMVPN for example you can break spoke to spoke traffic flow. While summarizing at hub you need to take into account split horizon and next hop for EIGRP.